# PayPal Instant Payment Notification Warning

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We always get this message from paypal. The payments are going in and the url in the message is correct.

Is there a way to stop these messages?

```
>Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment
>Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:
>
>http://sitename.com/payment/postbackPaypalSignUp/
>
>If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider
>that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider
>with the above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be
>disabled for your account.
>
>Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.
>
>
>Thanks,
>
>PayPal
```

Comment: I am also getting the same problem. But the payment is successfully logged into our system. Do you get the problem fixed?

Answer (score 0):

IPNs to that URL are failing. You can see the log somewhere at PayPal. You must fix your IPN handler. Check its logs too.

Comment: Hi, payments are successfully logged into our system and the IPN handlers are running for a long time without modifications. We have several IPN handlers for specific payments and then we override that url mentioned above in the email using the notify_url variable. Could it be an issue with our hosting?