# Paypal ipn warnings

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have the same issue like [PayPal Instant Payment Notification Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896575/paypal-instant-payment-notification-warning). I have two sites. I have the ipn url set in paypal account to site1. But I'm sending notify_url in paypal form for current site. My verification code on both sites:

```
public function paymentCheck()
{
    $request = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $request .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($request) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp)
        return false;
    else {
        fputs ($fp, $header . $request);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        fclose ($fp);
    }

    return true;
}
```

My sites handle ipn. All working fine. But some of paypal messages is failing and they turned it off. Do you have any ideas, what can cause warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that for some reason PayPal is getting something other than a 200 OK response back from your script.  If it looks like your script is working it could mean that all of the tasks are completing, but then an issue at the very end causes a failure that you don't even see other than the fact that PayPal isn't getting a good response back.

You need to check your web server logs for the times when your IPN script was hit and look at the results.  You'll probably find a bunch of them that show 500 or something other than 200.  You should also be able to see the error details there, too, and get it resolved.